# Inscript keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have an Xfce desktop installed on my computer. I want to use an inscript keyboard (Bangla) on it. I have found the keyboard in language layout, but I am having trouble to see its inscript variant. It is showing some other input source. How do I add it or simply change it? Please help. I have attached a screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try installing `ibus-m17n` and reboot to see more Bangla keyboard options.

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt install ibus-m17n
```

Enter your password when prompted. Nothing will show on the terminal and the cursor won't move as you type the password. This is normal.

Then close all applications and reboot the computer.

Then try again. You should see **Bangla (Baishakhi Inscript)** as one of the choices.

Hope this helps